# The import com.badlogic cannot be resolved in Java Project Libgdx Setup

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I've just tried to setup Libgdx to start making games, i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9fs1PVTyUc&feature=youtu.be
 in conjunction with the libgdx grdale setup. However an error shows up in the Java project which says:

```
The import com.badlogic cannot be resolved
```

I am using Eclipse for Java IDE. I believe I have the Android SDK installed. I think it may be to do with the setup but i think the latest updates are there and i tried deleting '.m2'ccahe, which is not there any more btw after i deleted it (not been replaced), but this didnt work. Any ideas?

heres my code for the java proect:

```
import com.badlogic.gmx.Game;

public class GameMain extends Game{

}//'com.badlogic 'gets an error and so does 'Game'
```

[image]

Comment: import com.badlogic.gdx.Game not gmx, also make sure you have installed the gradle plugin and make sure to follow the instructions here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html

Comment: @Jyro117 changed to gdx but still same error

Comment: please attach a screenshot of your project expanded in Eclipse so that I can see what your project setup looks like.

Comment: @Jyro117 please see the new edit thanks!

Comment: Your game code should go into game1-core instead of game1-ios. game1-ios is for ios specific code and not anything to do with the actual game. Minor side note: iOS requires a Mac computer and won't work on Windows.

Comment: @Jyro117 i actually created a new java project called CreateGame (open in new edit, sorry), it was not in the ios, should i continue to use this is project or move the files to game1-core? thanks

Comment: The files libgdx needs must be added to the project (which involves editing the project setup and I would only suggest you do this if you are an experienced developer). It would be much easier for you to use game1-core to start with as all of the dependencies are setup for you. Make sure you look over https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Eclipse this should help you as well.

Comment: @Jyro117 thank you very much, if u leave an answer i would be happy to accept it as you have been very useful, informative and returned to help, thanks again

Comment: No worries, best of luck in your game development endeavours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is your eclipse project "CreateGame" is not setup correctly. It is missing the files needed to use libgdx.

Possible Solutions:

- Use the [libgdx project setup tool](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle) and then follow the [instructions here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Eclipse) to import the project to eclipse. (easy)
- Add the missing library files to the project (hard)

Also make sure your game code is going into the game-core project as this project is used by each platform you are targeting.